# Tkinter: loading / processing input file in new frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a small program, using Tkinter, that will open your datafile, perform some actions on the data, and save that as a new file.

I would like to separate the selection of the input file with its processing, hence I am using two different frames.  However, I am having some issues with properly initializing the ProcessPage frame, as it would always read in my (undefined) filename, trying to load data, before the user has specified the actual file name.

Most likely, I have either wrongly tested global variables or am missing something crucial compared to the init__ of the ProcessPage.

How do I ensure that the ProcessPage frame does not try to read in the data during the init__ before the user has declared the proper file?

I am fairly unexperienced with Tkinter, so I might be missing something obvious here.

Thanks!

Edit (10/01/2017): Added an additional method (load_file) to the ProcessPage class; called this method from get_filename; and declared time and data as global parameters.  However, I am unsure whether the latter is good practice.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import numpy as np

global time, data
time, data = np.array([]), np.array([])

class MainApp(tk.Tk):    
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand = True)    
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (LoadPage, ProcessPage):
      frame = F(container, self)
      self.frames[F] = frame
      frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    self.show_frame(LoadPage)

  def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class LoadPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Browse', command = lambda: self.get_filename(controller))
    button1.pack()

    self.filename = tk.StringVar()
    self.filename.set('No File Selected')

    labelFile = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.filename)
    labelFile.pack()

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text='Proceed and process my data', command = lambda: controller.show_frame(ProcessPage))
    button2.pack()


  def get_filename(self, controller):
    global time, data
    fname = askopenfilename()
    if fname:
        self.filename.set(fname)
        # Extra line below  (10/01/2017)
        controller.frames[ProcessPage].load_file(fname)

class ProcessPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

  # Extra method, as suggested   (10/01/2017)
  def load_file(self, filename):
    global time, data
    time, data = np.loadtxt(filename, usecols=(0,1), unpack=True)



app = MainApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't do it in `__init__`. In processPage create function which load file and execute it manually only when you get filename.

Comment: if you create function `load_file()` in `procesPage` then in `loadPage` in `get_filename()` you could execute `controller.frames[processPage].load_file(fname)`

Comment: BTW: we use `CamelCase` names for classes - `LoadPage`, `ProcessPage` - It makes code more readable. Even SO uses light blue color to show classes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!   I presume this new function / method would fully replace the LoadPage frame?

Comment: no, you need class `LoadPage` and `load_file()` inside this class. Without class `LoadPage` you will don't have this page.

Comment: I see what you are pointing at.  Thanks!  I now seem to have a working example, but I am not entirely sure if it is fully correct.  Should I replace / edit the code above with the updated version or place it as an answer?

Comment: you can append to current question (but without changing oryginal question) or you can put it as answer if it resolves your problem.

Comment: I have updated the example.  However, I am unsure if the global variables are the correct way to go.

Comment: if you will use this data only in `ProcessPage` then create `self.time` and `self.data` in `ProcessPage.__init__`. If you will need them in other pages then you can create `self.time` and `self.data` in `MainApp.__init__` and have access in all pages as `controller.time` and `controller.data`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final implementation, where the method ProcessPage.load_file() is called to read in the data.  The data is read in and stored as variables (self.time and self.data) within ProcessPage.

The data is read in from LoadPage.start_processing(), which is now linked towards button2, hence the browsing of the data and the read-in are separated.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import numpy as np

class MainApp(tk.Tk):    
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand = True)    
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (LoadPage, ProcessPage):
      frame = F(container, self)
      self.frames[F] = frame
      frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    self.show_frame(LoadPage)

  def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class LoadPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Browse', command = self.get_filename)
    button1.pack()

    self.filename = tk.StringVar()
    self.filename.set('No File Selected')

    labelFile = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.filename)
    labelFile.pack()

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text='Proceed and process my data', command = lambda: self.start_processing(controller))
    button2.pack()


  def get_filename(self):
    fname = askopenfilename()
    if fname:
        self.filename.set(fname)
        return

  # Extra method below  (10/01/2017)
  def start_processing(self, controller):
    controller.frames[ProcessPage].load_file(self.filename.get())
    controller.show_frame(ProcessPage)

class ProcessPage(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    # Initialised the variables (10/01/2017)
    self.time = np.array([])
    self.data = np.array([])

  # Extra method, as suggested   (10/01/2017)
  def load_file(self, filename):
    self.time, self.data = np.loadtxt(filename, usecols=(0,1), unpack=True)   

app = MainApp()
app.mainloop()
```